# How to compare outputs of erosion from ArcSWAT and RUSLE from ArcGIS?

Tags: arcmap, spatial-analyst, arcgis-desktop, erosion, rusle

I calculated water erosion in [ArcSWAT](http://swat.tamu.edu/software/arcswat/) and I also calculated erosion by RUSLE

```
http://35.8.121.139/rusle/
```

equation in ArcGIS. Now I need to compare these two (from [ArcSWAT](http://swat.tamu.edu/software/arcswat/) I used SYLD- assumed sediment routing in t/ha/y and in rusle erosion also in t/ha/y), I used zonal statistics for rusle, but my results are wrong and I think I am using the wrong instructions on how to do it, does anybody know how can I compare these two?

Comment: What version of ArcGIS are you using? Are you using the Spatial Analyst extension? Are you able to provide links to arcswat and RUSLE which are both terms unfamiliar to me, please?

Comment: [ArcSWAT](http://swat.tamu.edu/software/arcswat/) is a surface water modeling module/add-in that is part of [SWAT](http://swat.tamu.edu/).

Comment: if anybody is interested, now i know how to compare them. ArcSWAT computes also output USLE, which you can directly compare with RUSLE, or to compare SYLD from ArCSWAT(sediment runoff in t/ha/y) with RUSLE also in t/ha/y ( you use subbasins from ArcSWAT to create zonal statistics of RUSLE, parameter: MEAN) and then just to compare :) result supposed to be - erosion calculated by RUSLE is less then ArcSWAT because ArcSWAT also calculates influence of psysical laws of terrain.

Comment: i am interested in the following, how you use SWAT to calculate erosion. I know how to do the RUSLE part. then am also interested in how you compared both the RUSLE and SWAT. I would appreciate a step by step tutorial on how to use SWAT to calculate erosion and how to compare SWAT and RUSLE.

Comment: Hi @OlajireOlabanji, could you please ask this as a [new question](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) instead of posting it as an _answer_. You can always include a link to this post in your question to show you did some research. You should also consider taking a very quick [tour](http://gis.stackexchange.com/tour) to see how this (and essentially other StackExchange) sites operate :)

Comment: I want the person that posted this to help me out... it s actually thesame question as hers

Comment: Considering the original poster hasn't logged in for over 2 years now, I doubt you will get help from her ;)